# Is the following SQL query is efficient?

Tags: sql, optimization

SQL Query Problem: **Find all animals who eats all animals except itself**

I have written Following query & gives results 
but i would like to know

**is there any other better approach?**

SQL Query -

```
select * from [dbo].Animal a
where (
(
(select COUNT(distinct id) from [dbo].Animal b
where  b.id <> a.id)
=
(select COUNT(*) from [dbo].Food
where  pId = a.id and aId <> a.id)
) 
AND
(select COUNT(*) from [dbo].Food
where  pId = a.id and aId = a.id) = 0
)
```

**Animal table**

```
id  name
--------
1   Ant
2   Bear
3   Cat
4   Dog
```

**Food table (here pId is predatorId)**

```
pId aId
-------
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
3   1
3   2
3   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I would use aggregation:

```
select pid
from food
group by pid
having count(*) = (select count(*) - 1 from animal) and
       sum(case when aid = pid then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=271649c004eb42f09aabee40dfa7f668) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No It displays 2 (as 2 eats 2) also. and How to display animal name?

Comment: @nalcoder . . . You would join to the `animal` table and use the name in both the `select` and the `group by`.  I'll let you do that.

Comment: @nalcoder . . . I just misinterpreted the question -- your question is clear, my misinterpretation.  I fixed the answer and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Small spin-off from what Gordon offered.  Since his query was explicitly excluding the self via the aid <> pid, that was allowing the #2 being included in the list.  I would add another LEFT JOIN on those that DO eat themselves and make sure its not one of those

```
select 
      f.pid
   from 
      food f
         -- this is looking for the current predator
         -- in the food table and it allows itself to eat itself
         LEFT JOIN food f2
            on f.pid = f2.pid
           AND f2.pid = f2.aid

   where 
          f.aid <> f.pid
      -- and it is NOT a cannibalistic animal, 
      -- hence we do NOT want to find in the left join of F2
      AND f2.pid is NULL
   group by 
      f.pid
   having 
      count(*) = (select count(*) - 1 from animal);
```